# viewing questions by clicking on tags

Tags: support

Ive been using the Arqade for a while now and i recently noticed that when you navigate to tags and click on a tag, unlike on stackoverflow, it does not list all questions with that tag in it. It just lists the description of a tag and states that there are 0 questions tagged.

[image: What happens when you click on tag]

This pretty annoying since i want to easily navigate to the questions with the same tag i posted to start answering other peoples questions about the same game while i wait for my answer or just after i receive my answer.

I cant imagine why this behavior would be implemented by design so I'm pretty sure its a bug. (the same thing happens when you click on a tag on your own question)

Comment: Click on "Active" or "Newest".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per your screenshot, you're on the featured tab, which shows currently-bountied questions in that tag.

You should click "newest" up at the top to get the view you were expecting. Your tab selection at the top is persisted across page views, so you must have clicked on the featured tab somewhere at one point.

Comment: Dont forget that this applies to every SE site, but sites like Stackoverflow have hundreds of bounties questions.